# jQuery datepicker year change when select month, IE7

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, internet-explorer-7, datepicker

Our project using JSF1.2, Icefaces 1.8.2, jQuery UI component datepicker (veresion 1.8.14). Problem with IE7 (Firefox is fine). Problem will happen with following sequence: Select a date (for example, couple days befor doday). Note we have set year range from 1991 to 2012. Our business logic is print a document use that date (in code, called dateOfStudy) as title, once done, in the JSF back bean, I clear the calendar inputext date field to null. Now click datepicker icon again, the year corrtly shows 2011, select any previous month (for example go back to Auguest, 2011), problme happend right here: the year will change to 1991, can not keep at 2011.

The problem will not happen if I do not touch that date field (don't do clear, keep the old date). The problem will still appear even I just change the date font to other color via CSS (seems whenever I touch that field, datepicker will messed up). The problem will not happen if you click today once, or close datepicker, open again.

Seems the datepick need some initializtion after I cleared date?

I attached some code. I have trid method/option like setDate, onChangeMonthYear, beforShowDay, can not solve. Any help is appreciated !!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq("[id$=fmv]").live('click', function() {
        jq(this).datepicker( {
            showOn : 'focus',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
            yearRange : '-20:+1',
            showButtonPanel : true,
            closeText : 'Close'
        }).focus();
    });
});
</script>

<ice:inputText id="fmv"
                       style="background-image:url      ('../../../jquery/images/calendar1.png');
                       background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right;"
                       value="#{pItem.dateOfStudy}"
                       validator="#{pItem.validate}"
                       partialSubmit="true"
                       name="fmv"         
                       valueChangeListener="#{pItem.dateChangeListener}"> 
                       </ice:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

When backbean clear or change input text in calendar inputText, I think that causes a focus event, and calendar confused under IE7. The reason I am using showOn focus is the code is in a table AJAX display area, so use calendar show on image button not work since the button image will not show when AJAX update comes back (the jQuery calendar will not get called), which force me to use showOn focus. I finally solved this year change problem by adding the following refresh calendar line after the final .focus():

```
jq(this).datepicker("setDate",jq("[id$=fmv]").datepicker("getDate"));
```

things working fine now. I am not sure how to make this call only when backbean clean the calendar date, but performance seems ok.